# Why must a class implementing an interface invoke its default super methods statically?

Tags: java, interface

If I were to have an interface as such:

```
interface U {
  default void execute() {
    ...
  }
}
```

and a class implementing it:

```
class V implements U {
  @override
  void execute() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Why would class `V`'s `execute` require `U`'s `execute` to be invoked as `U.super.execute()` rather than `super.execute()`?